# How to make a custom ListView page in SuiteCRM

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I need to make a page in SuiteCRM (v7.9 -- based loosely on Sugar 6.5 CE) that has a list of objects (of a custom module), with checkboxes in front of each one.  So far, so good: that's a standard ListView.

The catch is that only *some* records should be in the list (filtering on whether there is an associated row in a related custom module/object).

This page needs to be distinct from the "regular" list for this module, which should indeed list all records.

It seems to me it makes sense to use a custom "action" to access this page view, and I can get my custom action code to fire with the right URL.

But I don't see how to hook in the filtering.  At first, it looked like the process_record logic hook might be helpful here, but it just gives the bean for every record to be displayed.  Unless there's a flag "display this record" that I'm not seeing, that's not so helpful.

Ideally, of course, I'd like to be able to inject a different WHERE clause in my custom controller action before calling

```
parent::action_listview();
```

to display the page, but I'm not seeing doc to indicate how that might work.  I would include source code, but so far, the line above is everything (but boilerplate) that's in the `controller.php` file.

Comment: Do you want to have a complete custom view with your own html or just default filtering a listview ?

Comment: @mrbarletta I _think_ what I need to do can be accomplished by letting the users use the sorting features that come with a default listview.  OTOH, if you want to mention where to look (for doc or code) or how to approach it if custom HTML is needed, that would be very welcome.

Comment: So far, I'm finding programming for SuiteCRM to be very stressful, because "the book" leaves so many gaps, and there's little other doc specific to SuiteCRM, and it's very hard for a noob to know which Sugar CE doc applies to SuiteCRM and which doesn't.  I mean, seriously, I've programmed professionally in more than a dozen languages, and this is one of my more frustrating starting-out experiences.  And I've done _a lot_ of PHP and plenty of JS before this.

Comment: @Jeffiekins have you tried using view.list.php?

Comment: @Jeffiekins could you explain how you created a custom action in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of listview in custom folder and then override the listview's listViewProcess() method and insert your query there:

```
function listViewProcess()        // generating listview 
{
    $this->processSearchForm();
    if($this->where==''){
        $this->where.="leads.status='Converted'";
    }
    $this->lv->searchColumns = $this->searchForm->searchColumns;
        if(!$this->headers)
            return;
    $this->lv->setup($this->seed, 'custom/modules/Leads/ListView/ListViewGeneric.tpl', $this->where, $this->params);
    echo $this->lv->display();
}
```

More info: http://wiki-crm-forum.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9420&p=32674&hilit=listViewProcess&sid=21907ecd28734a726f61f7017a7e9a24#p32674

Another tested working example can be found here: 
[How to hard code the where condition in list view ,basic search,advance search in sugar CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761361/how-to-hard-code-the-where-condition-in-list-view-basic-search-advance-search-i)

P.S: I'm not so sure about "v7.9 -- based loosely on Sugar 6.5 CE" I'd say it's 95% identical apart from API stuff

Comment: The first link, to wiki-crm-forum.com seems to have challenge authentication, I couldn't access it.

Answer (score 0):

for custom modules in SuiteCRM.

You may change in function create_new_list_query.